# how to combine filters in nsclient check_files?

Tags: nagios

What ever I try only the first condition takes

This seems like it should work but it does not

```
"filter=written > -2d and type!=dir"
```

Folders are included in the result

Answer (score 0):

Never  mind, it seems I need type='file'.